# Ubuntu Software Updater > Settings & Livepatch (Software & Updates) not working

Tags: updates, software-center, update-manager, repository, software-sources

---

Hey Guys,
I  have following problem for several months and I don't know how to solve it.
Every time I start the Software Updater, the button Settings & Livepatch does not do anything. If I search for Software & Updates, the name of the application is not shown in the search results. Even in System Settings I can't execute the Software & Updates button.

```
sudo apt-cache policy 
Package files:
 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     release a=now
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-desktop/ppa/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=LP-PPA-ubuntu-desktop,a=focal,n=focal,l=PPA for Ubuntu Desktop,c=main,b=i386
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-desktop/ppa/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=LP-PPA-ubuntu-desktop,a=focal,n=focal,l=PPA for Ubuntu Desktop,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams stable/main amd64 Packages
     release o=ms-teams stable,a=stable,n=stable,l=ms-teams stable,c=main,b=amd64
     origin packages.microsoft.com
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/lutris-team/lutris/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=LP-PPA-lutris-team-lutris,a=focal,n=focal,l=Lutris stable,c=main,b=i386
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/lutris-team/lutris/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=LP-PPA-lutris-team-lutris,a=focal,n=focal,l=Lutris stable,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxuprising/java/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=LP-PPA-linuxuprising-java,a=focal,n=focal,l=Oracle Java,c=main,b=i386
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxuprising/java/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=LP-PPA-linuxuprising-java,a=focal,n=focal,l=Oracle Java,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
1001 http://archive.lambdalabs.com/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     release o=lambdalabs.com,n=focal,l=Lambda Labs Ubuntu repository (Focal),c=main,b=i386
     origin archive.lambdalabs.com
1001 http://archive.lambdalabs.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     release o=lambdalabs.com,n=focal,l=Lambda Labs Ubuntu repository (Focal),c=main,b=amd64
     origin archive.lambdalabs.com
 500 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main amd64 Packages
     release v=1.0,o=Google LLC,a=stable,n=stable,l=Google,c=main,b=amd64
     origin dl.google.com
 500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal/stable amd64 Packages
     release o=Docker,a=focal,l=Docker CE,c=stable,b=amd64
     origin download.docker.com
 500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main all Packages
     release o=dl.winehq.org,a=focal,n=focal,l=winehq,c=main,b=all
     origin dl.winehq.org
 500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     release o=dl.winehq.org,a=focal,n=focal,l=winehq,c=main,b=i386
     origin dl.winehq.org
 500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     release o=dl.winehq.org,a=focal,n=focal,l=winehq,c=main,b=amd64
     origin dl.winehq.org
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/multiverse i386 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal-security,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse,b=i386
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal-security,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse,b=amd64
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe i386 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal-security,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=i386
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal-security,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=amd64
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/restricted i386 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal-security,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=i386
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/restricted amd64 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal-security,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=amd64
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main i386 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal-security,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=i386
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal-security,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=amd64
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 100 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe i386 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal-backports,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=i386
     origin de.archive.ubuntu.com
 100 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe amd64 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal-backports,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=amd64
     origin de.archive.ubuntu.com
 100 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/main i386 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal-backports,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=i386
     origin de.archive.ubuntu.com
 100 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/main amd64 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal-backports,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=amd64
     origin de.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal-updates,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse,b=i386
     origin de.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal-updates,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse,b=amd64
     origin de.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe i386 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal-updates,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=i386
     origin de.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal-updates,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=amd64
     origin de.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted i386 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal-updates,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=i386
     origin de.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal-updates,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=amd64
     origin de.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main i386 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal-updates,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=i386
     origin de.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal-updates,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=amd64
     origin de.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/multiverse i386 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse,b=i386
     origin de.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/multiverse amd64 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse,b=amd64
     origin de.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe i386 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=i386
     origin de.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=amd64
     origin de.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/restricted i386 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=i386
     origin de.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/restricted amd64 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=amd64
     origin de.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=i386
     origin de.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=amd64
     origin de.archive.ubuntu.com


sudo apt update
    Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxuprising/java/ubuntu focal InRelease
    Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/lutris-team/lutris/ubuntu focal InRelease       
    Hit:3 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease                 
    Hit:4 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                      
    Hit:5 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal InRelease                 
    Hit:6 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
    Hit:7 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease              
    Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-desktop/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease       
    Hit:9 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease            
    Hit:10 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams stable InRelease          
    Hit:11 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease              
    Hit:12 http://archive.lambdalabs.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                   
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    All packages are up to date.

sudo apt full-upgrade
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    Calculating upgrade... Done
    The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
      libfwupdplugin1 libnvidia-cfg1-470 libnvidia-common-470
      libnvidia-compute-470 libnvidia-compute-470:i386 libnvidia-decode-470
      libnvidia-decode-470:i386 libnvidia-encode-470 libnvidia-encode-470:i386
      libnvidia-extra-470 libnvidia-extra-470:i386 libnvidia-fbc1-470
      libnvidia-fbc1-470:i386 libnvidia-gl-470 libnvidia-gl-470:i386
      libnvidia-ifr1-470 libnvidia-ifr1-470:i386 nvidia-compute-utils-470
      nvidia-utils-470 xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-470
    Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
    0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

[Screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fzUD.png)
[Screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdIMI.png)
[Screenshot3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HwBT.png)

Comment: Hello. It is not clear what you are doing. Have you simply tried a sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get upgrade?

Comment: Even better: `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade` . Do that and report back by [edit]ing the question

Comment: I have done so, but the problem still is occurring. The Screenshots maybe tell you more, because the graphical interface is not working.

Comment: By any chance did you remove python?

Comment: I don't think so, but I have installed lambda labs, which does contain several python packages for machine learning.
When I run the command python --version, I get:
Python 3.8.10

/usr/bin % ls | grep python 
dh_python2
dh_python3-ply
ipython3
python
python2
python2.7
python3
python3-config
python3-futurize
python3-pasteurize
python3-wsdump
python3.8
python3.8-config